# How do I extract the year part of an observable ISO Date

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, observable

I have an `angular component class` that updates an interface with `Object` records like this `[{"examYear":"2001-01-02T00:00:00.000+00:00"},{...}]` received from an `Observable GET` call to the backend service.
The `angular Service` class has this signature:

```
export someService{
private dateEndpoint="http://xxx";
constructor(private httpClient:HttpClient){}

fetchDateObj():Observable<SubjectDate[]>{
return this.httpClient.get<SubjectDate[]>(this.dateEndpoint);
}

}
```

The `SubjectDate class` is

```
export class SubjectDate {
examYear: Date;
constructor (examYear: Date){
this.examYear=examYear;
}
}
```

The `component class` that calls the `fetchDateObj()` method of my `service component` has a method like this

```
getDates(){
this.someService.fetchDateObj().subscribe(dateObjArr=>{
this.subjectDates=dateObjArr;

//Map record to examYear then extract only unique dates
this.dateArr=(this.subjectDates.map(x=>x.examYear)).filter(this.isUnique);

//log the year of each unique date
this.dateArr.forEach(x=>x.getFullYear());
}
```

the `callback function` is like this

```
isUnique(curr:Date,index: number,arr:Date[]):boolean{
return (index === arr.indexOf(curr))
}
```

Though the interface is correctly updated with `Date` record like `Jan 2,2002` after parsing with `angular date pipe`, but I expected to have a log of something like `2001` etc as the full year, but instead I keep getting this browser console error `ERROR TypeError: x.getFullYear is not a function at z.component.ts at Array.forEach(<anonymous>)...`

Comment: Where is the `dateArr.push(new Date(isostring))` in your code?

Comment: All your types say `Date` object which does indeed have that `getFullYear` method but your data sample has ISO date *strings*. Which is it? Typescript can't save you on the wire.

Comment: @mplungjan ``dateArr`` is a private attribute of my component initialized to empty array like this ``dateArr:Date[]=[]``. So the return of the ``map`` call is assigned to it

Comment: @Chinedu mplungjan is (I think) making the same point I am: you have strings and you aren't parsing them into date objects anywhere.

Comment: @mplungjan thanks , it works now as desired

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing I did was to create a new Date with the returned `ISO` date string and it worked as expected.

```
this.dateArr=(this.subjectDates.map(x=>x.examYear)).filter(this.isUnique).map(isoString=>new Date(isoString))
```

Comment: I suggest you filter on the ISO STRINGS before making the dates! Saves a lot of processing if there are many identical dates since your test will be not only converting every single string to Date but ALSO might be converting every single date to string in the comparison

Comment: @mplungjan 